# Keycloak 16 docker default ${jboss.server.data.dir} location

Tags: linux, docker, keycloak

I would like to add a password-blacklist to Keycloak 16 running in a docker container. I have tried to add the blacklist to `/opt/jboss/keycloak/password-blacklists/` and `/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/password-blacklists/` but in both places the file could not be found.

The documentations says the following: *"Blacklist files resolve against `${jboss.server.data.dir}/password-blacklists/` by default."*

So what is path is the default `${jboss.server.data.dir}` using the docker container?

Comment: There won't be any files present at the above location. You have to create one. Go to `${jboss.server.data.dir}/` and create folder `password-blacklists` if not present. Then create a text file and add blacklisted password (each in new line)

Comment: @Abhijeet Thank you for your reaction, I tried creating the folders and adding a blacklist text file. But the one could not be found. I'm looking for the default `${jboss.server.data.dir}` that is used in the docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Command%20line%20parameters.html

```
jboss.server.data.dir = jboss.server.base.dir/data 
->
jboss.server.base.dir = jboss.home.dir/standalone 
->
jboss.home.dir = Set by standalone.sh to $JBOSS_HOME
```

and `$JBOSS_HOME` is:

```
docker run --rm -ti --entrypoint bash quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:16.1.0 -c 'echo $JBOSS_HOME'
/opt/jboss/keycloak
```

So `jboss.server.data.dir` = `/opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/data/`

Keep in mind that Keycloak is running under `jboss` user (uid=1000), so set file permissions accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for you reaction, it is great to read that I was close. The ultimate solution in the end was that the file permission was not set correctly. So thank you for adding that piece of information.